# Creating a shortcut - Atom

Tags: django, atom-editor

I need to use a shortcut which creates `{%  %}` in html file. I use emmet but it doesn't support this kind of syntax. 
Do you know any other packages which allows to do this or how to create shortcut like this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what syntax this is

Comment: It's for django bulit-in template tags in html doc

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [custom snippets](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) for Django. There used to be a package for Zen Coding (the predecessor to Emmet), but since the snippets are no longer stored in as XML but as JSON (and the new format is much simpler!) Yet, you could use this as a reference to create your own snippets.

Alternatively, take a look at the non-Emmet [Django Snippets](https://github.com/mattseymour/sublime-django).